# Add AdMob Interstitial in React native without the need for the onPress event

Tags: react-native, admob

I am trying to add Admob Interstitial in react native, but I want the ad to appear without using it a button (onPress) event, it is possible to do this and I have also tried to make the ad run from interval of time, I have thought to use setTimeOut (function, 1000), I don't know if it is feasible to use it because I want the ad to appear every so often, while the application is running.

THank you!

```
interstitialDidClose() {
    AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync((error) => error && log(error));
   }

  componentDidMount() {
    AdMintroducir el código aquíobRewarded.setTestDeviceID([Config.AdMob.deviceID]);
    AdMobRewarded.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917');

    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('rewarded', reward =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => rewarded', reward),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adLoaded', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adLoaded'),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adFailedToLoad', error =>
      console.warn(error),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adOpened', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adOpened'),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('videoStarted', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => videoStarted'),
    );
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adClosed', () => {
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adClosed');
      AdMobRewarded.requestAdAsync().catch(error => console.warn(error));
    });
    AdMobRewarded.addEventListener('adLeftApplication', () =>
      console.log('AdMobRewarded => adLeftApplication'),
    );

    AdMobRewarded.requestAdAsync().catch(error => console.warn(error));

    AdMobInterstitial.setTestDeviceID([Config.AdMob.deviceID]);
    AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712');

    AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener('adLoaded', () =>
      console.log('AdMobInterstitial adLoaded'),
    );
    AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener('adFailedToLoad', error =>
      console.warn(error),
    );
    AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener('adOpened', () =>
      console.log('AdMobInterstitial => adOpened'),
    );
    AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener('adClosed', () => {
      console.log('AdMobInterstitial => adClosed');
      AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync().catch(error => console.warn(error));
    });
    AdMobInterstitial.addEventListener('adLeftApplication', () =>
      console.log('AdMobInterstitial => adLeftApplication'),
    );

    AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync().catch(error => console.warn(error));
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    AdMobRewarded.removeAllListeners();
    AdMobInterstitial.removeAllListeners();
  }

  showRewarded() {
    AdMobRewarded.showAdAsync().catch(error => console.warn(error));

  }

  showInterstitial() {
   AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync().catch(error => console.warn(error))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
      title="Show Interstitial and preload next"
      onPress={this.showInterstitial}
    />
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For this i have used the code in React.js as follows :

```js
import {
  AdMobInterstitial,setTestDeviceIDAsync
} from 'expo-ads-admob';

export default class App extends Component {

 
  async componentDidMount(){
    await setTestDeviceIDAsync('EMULATOR');
      AdMobInterstitial.setAdUnitID('ca-app-pub-6726786803906385/1416335240'); 
      await AdMobInterstitial.requestAdAsync({ servePersonalizedAds: true});
     
      await AdMobInterstitial.showAdAsync();
     
   
    
  }

  render() {
    return (
    
    
    -------);}}
```

But I am not getting how to insert intervals of interstitial ads.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to call admob interstitial without any event, for this reason Only I've used

```
function(){
setTimeOut (this.showInterstitial(), 1000)
}

 render() {
return (
  <Button
  title="Show Interstitial and preload next"
  onPress={this.function()}
/>
)
```

}